# Can't access classes in Portable Class Library

Tags: java, c#, .net, xamarin

I'm new to mobile development and Xamarin. I am trying to make an instance of a class which is found in another project under the same solution (HotDog and HotDogDataService). I get the red underline the using saying `The type or namespace name 'RaysHotDogs' could not be found`.

Why can't I instantiate these classes in this project? The classes are public.

[image]

Comment: Is your pcl project building and did you add a reference to your android project?

Comment: Nope, doesn't look like it actually. http://iforce.co.nz/i/zni0t0dg.cmj.png
What does that mean?

Comment: in one of your layout files, if you look at the xml you probably have invalid property, It's one one of the relative layouts as far as I can see

Comment: It was exactly that. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your projects is not being build, judging by the error message provided - in one of your layout files, if you look at the `xml` you probably have invalid property, It's one one of the relative layouts as far as I can see.